# Where does Skype store the avatar pictures of my contacts?

Tags: windows, skype, pictures

I'd like to know where does Skype running on Windows 7 store the profile pictures of my contacts and how can I access them on my PC?

Answer (score 9):

> #### Before you start
>
> [SJG's answer is an easy solution.](https://superuser.com/a/860803/233899) Continue only if you *really* want to extract big and/or small avatars from your skype client.

Avatars can be found in **`main.db`** database, **`Contacts`** table, **`avatar_image`** column, or inside **`profile_attachments`** column, as noted in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/499242)

## Where is `main.db`?

Here:

`%APPDATA%\Skype\your_skype_login\main.db`

you can paste `%APPDATA%\Skype` in windows start menu search bar and press enter.
([What is “%AppData%”?](https://superuser.com/q/632891) and [What are environment variables?](https://superuser.com/q/284342))

If you are going to mess with skype database, copy **both `main.db` and `main.db-journal`** somewhere else. Do not open (and edit) main.db directly if unsure. **Do not ignore this warning.**

Luckily, you don't have to exit skype to copy it's database.

## How do I open it?

`main.db` is an [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database.

Open database file in [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

> You can open SQLite database with [SQLite studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/) which is cool and worth trying, but this time use [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) because it can easily export binary column to file.

Navigate to `Browse data` tab, Table `Contacts`, column `avatar_image` (21th currently) is the blob you are looking at. Double-click it, hit "Export" and save to a `.jpg` file.

I had to remove null-byte at the beginning of extracted file. You can, of course, do it with HEX-editor, but you better **delete "NUL" at the beginning with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which will not corrupt binary file like any other text editor.**

And viola, this is the `.jpg` avatar you are looking at.

## Where is a bigger avatar? / avatar_image is empty

Check inside **`profile_attachments`** column.

After saving, delete everything from the beginning of the file to the

***[NUL]*** ÿØÿà **[NUL]** **[DLE]** JFIF

Including the first ***[NUL]***, so the file will begin with

ÿØÿà **[NUL]** **[DLE]** JFIF

Note that `ÿØÿà` is a Windows-1252 representation of binary data. This is strongly depends on your windows locale, so you better look for JFIF part

> #### All the information about formats is kinjdly provided by [Guillaume Brunerie's answer to "Where does Skype save my contact's avatars in Linux?"](https://superuser.com/a/499242) so upvote his answer

Answer (score 8):

You can see it online if the user’s profile is public.

This link will take you to the Echo user’s profile avatar: [Echo Avatar](http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar)

The link is: http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar

To get a higher resolution picture use the `size` parameter.

- http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=s
- http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=m
- http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=l

Replace `echo` in the above URLs with your contact’s Skype ID

Comment: This is IMO the best Answer!

Comment: To get a higher resolution picture you can use the "size" parameter.

http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=s

http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=m

http://api.skype.com/users/echo/profile/avatar?size=l

So far those are the only three sizes I discovered that work.

Comment: No more working. Skype API requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 or Windows 8 the full path is `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Skype\Pictures`. Don't forget to enable the hidden files in Windows Explorer or you won't be able to see the Folder AppData.

Comment: Right, but those are pictures of me and not my **CONTACT'S** avatars.